# How to arrange a pair of different functions so as to indeed be run in parallel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, threadpool

I want to execute two functions in parallel and want to verify that they are running in parallel. here I am running 2 functions in parallel but the output I am getting is different. ideally, they should finish at the same time

I am using windows 10 OS hence cannot use Ray. Even cannot use pool since the functions I am using will be different

Code:

```
import datetime
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
import datetime

def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())

def f(name):
    info('function f')
    print('hello', name)


def func1():
    for i in range(1):
        print('function 1 running')
        for j in range(10000):
            for k in range(10000):
                a=1
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    return


def func2():
    for i in range(1):
        print('function 2 running')
        for j in range(10000):
            for k in range(10000):
                a=1
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    info('main line')
    p1 = Process(target=func1())
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=func2())
    p2.start()
```

Output:

```
main line

module name: __main__

parent process: 17284

process id: 2372

function 1 running

2019-07-07 12:00:44.512577

function 2 running

2019-07-07 12:00:50.100357
```

Expected Output:

```
function 1 running

function 2 running

2019-07-07 12:00:44.512577

2019-07-07 12:00:44.512577
```

Comment: This is a very common mistake: `Process(target=func1())` this *first* calls `func1()`, whcih executes on the main thread, then starts a new process with `target=None` (so which does nothing). Change it to `Process(target=func1)`. You want to pass the function `func1` as `target`, not its result. Unfortunately most IDEs will always autocomplete the `()` if they see that you are writing a function so it's easy to make this mistake if you are not careful

Comment: I tried this as well but it does not execute 
Modified Code:
**p1 = Process(target=func1)

    p1.start()

    p2 = Process(target=func2)

    p2.start()**

Output got:

**main line

module name: __main__

parent process: 17284

process id: 2372**

it seems it's not running

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
    p1 = Process(target=func1())
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=func2())
    p2.start()
```

which evaluates both functions (sequentially) in the current process,
and hands off the `None` result as the `target` parameter.

Instead you want to execute

```
    p1 = Process(target=func1)
    ...
    p2 = Process(target=func2)
```

which hands off a callable without evaluating the callable.

Comment: I tried this as well but it does not execute 
Modified Code:
**p1 = Process(target=func1)

    p1.start()

    p2 = Process(target=func2)

    p2.start()**

Output i got:

**main line

module name: __main__

parent process: 17284

process id: 2372**

it seems it's not running